# Map vs List specifics on method return

Tags: java, list, dictionary, set, duplicates

If I have some instance variable, let's say

```
private Map<String,MyClass> myMap;
```

and if I want to create a method to return myMap keys, do I have to guarantee that method return a Set (not to have duplicates) or is that already guaranteed by instance variable definition? Is there any case where duplicates can occur if I decide to return List type from method (I believe List is much more efficient than set)?

---

**Highlights**

---

```
public List<String> myKeys(){
    return
       myMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

***versus***

```
 public Set<String> myKeys(){
    return
       myMap.keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**In terms of:**

1. Duplicates existence;
2. Performance.

   **

### EDIT: Small error. I want to ask only about the keySet().

**

Comment: A map can contain duplicate _values_, so yes, duplicates can occur when you use a list. I wouldn't worry about performance (prematurely), just choose the data structure that fits your needs.

Comment: "I believe `List` is much more efficient than `Set`". It's not really an issue of belief. They're 2 different data structures, not to mention that they're both interfaces so the implementations differ in huge amounts. Don't try to write code based on what you believe in, everything is documented if you just bother to read a bit. Also as @JornVernee said, don't worry about performance. Concentrate on writing good code and worry about performance when it becomes a real issue, not just some gut feeling.

Comment: "I believe `List` is much more efficient than `Set`" A `List` (might be) more efficient than `Set` to iterate; A call to `contains` on a `Set` (might be) more efficient than on a `List`. Different data structures are "efficient" for different applications.

Answer (score 0):

If it is about the values: Of course we can have duplicates there.

No one prevents me to put something like

```
1, "foo"
2, "bar"
3, "foo"
```

into a map.

So while the keys can be expressed as a `Set`, the values can't.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` can't have duplicates on keys.

From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> An object that maps keys to values. A map **cannot contain duplicate keys**; each key can map to at most one value.

`Map` can have duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Keys of a Map are always unique, value may contain duplicates. If you collect the values into a Set, you won't have duplicates. If you collect to a List you may have duplicates.

But as you are using clone, you may end up with *effective* duplicates, even in a set.

Regarding performance, both ways should be more or less equal.

Answer (score 0):

Map is an interface, you can implement it any way you like.

However, you might want to follow common, assumed behaviour of a Map interface so not to confuse other programmers who might use your code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what are your needs. Subsequent modifying operations on a `List` will not guarantee that your collection will not contain duplicates, whereas such operations on a `Set` will do it.

In terms of performance, `Collections.toSet`'s contract guarantees a `Set`, and the implementation (JDK / OpenJDK) chooses `HashSet`.

So you will have to decide (depending on the subsequent operations to be performed) whether you should use a `HashSet` or a `List`.

You can take a decision based on time complexity or space, you should use the Big O cheat sheet, which you can find here: [BigO Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

Answer (score 0):

- java.util.Collection: Generic root interface in the collection hierarchy.
- java.util.Set: Collection that prevents the insertion of duplicate elements.
- java.util.List: Collection used when the elements need to be retrieved in some user-defined order.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, at least in OpenJDK, a `HashSet` is actually implemented using a `HashMap`. Specifically, the keys of a `Map` form a `Set` where the elements are unique.

`List`s, which are ordered sequences, on the other hand may have duplicate elements. The values of a `Map` do not form a `Set`, but rather a `List`.

You can of course however remove the duplicate elements of a `List` by putting it inside a `Set`, which is what you get by using `Collectors.toSet`.

The implementations of `Collectors.toList` and `Collectors.toSet` will give you an `ArrayList` and `HashSet`. The former provides fast lookup if you know the index (random access), and thus high performance when iterating through the array (this is due to the way modern CPUs work, data locality is important... In this case, Big-O-Complexity might not reflect real world scenarios). The latter provides primarily fast search, i.e: "does x belong to this set?"

So we have:

- Sets: no duplicates, usually un-ordered, fast `contains(...)`...
- Lists: ordered sequences, may have duplicates, (in case of arrays) fast iteration.

A `Set` can be implemented as a tree instead of a hashed map. And a `List` can be implemented as a linked-list. But the functions you use do not, so you should really consider the `Set` and `List` here to be `Hash Table` and `Array` in http://bigocheatsheet.com/

By the way: If I'm not mistaken, `collect` will actually do an implicit copy, so the view of `myMap.values()` is no longer live at this point and subsequent modifications to the resulting `List`/`Set` is not also done in the `Map`.